# Show div if radio value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show a `div` if a radio value is selected but then hide it again if a different value is selected

```
<input type="radio" name="timespan" id="timespan" value="ongoing" checked>On-going
<input type="radio" name="timespan" id="timespan" value="history">Historical


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.end_date').css('display','none');
              $('#timespan').click(function () {
               var selected = $(this).find(':checked').val();  
                  if(selected == 'history') {
                   $('.end_date').css('display','block');
                } else {
                   $('.end_date').css('display','none');
                 }
          });       
        });
</script>
```

If `history` is selected I want the elements with class `end_date` to show, otherwise if `ongoing` is selected I would like them to be hidden

Comment: Please check out the specification regarding ID's in HTML.

Comment: Are you getting errors? Is it not working?

Comment: @John, it's just not working

Comment: IDs can't be used more than once per page.

Comment: “I would like to” - then do it! Please explicitly ask your question (and describe expectations vs results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html markup should not include two elements with the same `id`, an `id` on the page should be unique, instead add the `class` timespan to both radio buttons.

In the code `.hide()` and `.show()` can be used in place of setting the `display` property to block or none.

Also instead of finding the `checked` radio button, you can assume that the clicked button will be checked.  This simplifies the code to `$(this).val();` instead of `$(this).find(':checked').val();`

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" class="timespan" name="timespan" value="ongoing" checked>On-going
<input type="radio" class="timespan" name="timespan" value="history">Historical
<div class="end_date">End Date</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.end_date').hide();
          $('.timespan').click(function () {
           var selected = $(this).val();  
              if(selected == 'history') {
               $('.end_date').show();
            } else {
               $('.end_date').hide();
             }
      });       
    });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hD4EY/

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 elements sharing the same `id`. That won't work. Change the `id` for the `history` button to something unique. You can also change your selector to a class selector:

```
$('.timespan').click(function () { ...
```

That makes sure that the click event applies to both radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As some have stated, you should not have HTML elements that share an ID. ID's are unique identifiers. Change the IDs for targeting. In my example, the jQuery generically checks radio input click events, and checks the ID. If they match your target of "historical" the desired div will become visible.
**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="timespan" id="ongoing" value="ongoing" checked>On-going
<input type="radio" id="historical" name="timespan" value="history">Historical

<div class='end-date'>End-date</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.end-date { display: none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
  var selected = $(this).attr('id');

  if(selected === 'historical') {
    $('.end-date').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.end-date').hide();
  }
});
```

[Codepen sketch.](http://cdpn.io/aIsLp)